# How can I use sumproduct to gather data on the sum of specific cells on another sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Just trying to create a small tracker to help me at my job. Not experienced in excel but just want to track specific aisles and how many units each aisle contains.
I'm trying to get the sum of specific aisles from another sheet. I kind of have the formula down just want to grab it from the columns in my other worksheet.
This is the code I'm using on cell AB4:

=SUMPRODUCT(--((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("246",A4:A5000))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH("247",A4:A5000)))>0),B4:B5000)

I just want to know where in my code I can put 'USS Waves'! so that my formula grabs cells from my other sheet.
[image]

I'm trying to grab from the other sheet to grab only the sums that are from aisles 246.247,248,249, and 250 in column A and get the sum of all of them from column B.

[image]

Comment: Could you show where the result should occur and what triggers the conditions? You mention cell `AB4` but your ur screenshot doesn't show rows or columns.

Comment: Consider setting up your data table as a proper, normalized table. Have one row of headings and each data element (e.g., USS Wave #) has a value in each data row. That will allow you to use pivot tables which don't depend on being on the same sheet. Also, pivot tables allow you to filter without altering formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice formula!

Insert the sheet name in front of the cell reference.
Also you need to add more conditions 246.247,248,249, and 250
And because you don't want to sum the 246,247, but the column to the right you need to change the column from A to B at the End of the formula.

Exchange the ; to comma ,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("246";'USS Waves'!$A$4:$A$5000))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH("247";'USS Waves'!$A$4:$A$5000))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH("248";'USS Waves'!$A$4:$A$5000))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH("249";'USS Waves'!$A$4:$A$5000))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH("250";'USS Waves'!$A$4:$A$5000)))>0);'USS Waves'!$B$4:$B$5000)
```

The formula above is mostly for text.
This formula below is for numbers and much shorter. Use this one.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('USS Waves'!$A$4:$A$5000>=246)*('USS Waves'!$A$4:$A$5000<=250)*('USS Waves'!$B$4:$B$5000))
```

So here you have only 2 conditions

```
>=246 and  <=250
```

if you want to understand this formula you can search for array formula with condition.
In this formula you also could change the Sumproduct to Sum

First conditon

```
('USS Waves'!$A$4:$A$5000>=246)
```

Second condition

```
('USS Waves'!$A$4:$A$5000<=250)
```

These results in a lot of False and True, and if you multiply this they turn to 0 and 1.
And wherever there is a match of both conditions you get a 1 and then this 1 i multiplied by the value in column B.

```
('USS Waves'!$B$4:$B$5000)
```

The sum function or Sumproduct function will then add all the values together.

Comment: Since it's numbers, not text you may use something like `=SUMPRODUCT(('USS Waves'!$A$4:$A$5000>=246)*('USS Waves'!$A$4:$A$5000<=250))`

Comment: @P.b Thank you! I learned so much today!